# How to test with Google Sign In for local development?

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I'm using Google's Java Client for server-side JWT authentication, along with their HTML snippet for the frontend. I'd like to do some testing locally to make sure my user flow works - but I'm not able to get my JWT from the frontend sign-in steps.

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button

I've entered my correct client ID, but I think it's upset that I used `localhost:3000/login` as the redirect route. Does anyone know how to set this up for local development?

`[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.`

I tried to fetch my actual JWT using the Google Sign In HTML snippet. I expected this to work fine, since it's my *actual* google account and a legitimate client ID.